# How can I calculate the average of maximums in QuickBase?

Tags: quickbase

**Context**: I'm working with student grade data and each students final grade is equal to :

```
average[max(Assignment1_submission#1, Assignment1_submission#2)+max(Assignment2_submission#1, Assignment1_submission#2)+...+max(Assignmentn_submission#1, Assignmentn_submission#2)]
```

I'm trying to find a way of calculating that metric in QuickBase. I'd assume this is in Table-to-table relationships in QuickBase.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would want to use table relationships to do this Quick Base.

You should have a Students table, an Assignments table and Submissions table with these relationships: Students < Assignments < Submissions.

You can use a summary field on the relationship between Assignments and Submissions to get the [Max Score] for all Submissions of that Assignment for that Student, then you can use another summary field on the relationship between Students and Assignments by using that [Max Score] for each Assignment to get the [Average Score] for each Student.

Hope that helps.
-Erich